# Authorize Attribute Interaction With Active Directory .NET Core 1.1, .Net Framework

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am currently using the `[Authorize]` attribute at the top of a controller aiming to restrict access to particular parts of my site based on AD groups. I am using IIS integrated authentication. The machine hosting the site sits on a domain and can talk to the domain controller. I am also using .NET Core 1.1 but have also tried this with the full .Net Framework producing the same results.

Currently I have 
`[Authorize(Roles = "Domain\\My_AD_Group")]` but can't get the AD group to actively update against the site. If I change the users in the group, force replication and rebuild the site locally nothing changes. If I restart my local machine after replication this seems to fix the problem and it reads the group permissions correctly. This same thing happens in IIS.

It seems like there are cached credentials sorted somewhere locally but am unsure if this is the case. Any help greatly appreciated.

Edit: I have also tried this in the full .Net Framework, having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating the user's group membership you could try running "Gpupdate /force" in windows command prompt after to narrow it down.

Or you could add another annotation to not cache the controller action:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
public ActionResult ControllerAction(int id
{
// stuff
}
```